# Debug socket communication in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets

I need to know the flow of the below given program:

Client Class:

```
1. Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 1101);
2. PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
3. write.println("Hello");
4. write.close();
```

Server Class:

```
1. ServerSocket sersock = new ServerSocket(1101);
2. sock = sersock.accept();
3. InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
4. BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(read);
5. System.out.println(buf.readLine());
6. buf.close();
```

When I run the server class and then the client class, how does the flow of the program work?

Comment: Exactly how it reads.

Comment: Start by reading the `ServerSocket` API for `new ServerSocket(int)` and `accept()`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html

Comment: set the debug points and run it in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It flows exactly how it reads.

Server binds the socket to port 1101, listens for connections

```
1. ServerSocket sersock = new ServerSocket(1101);
2. sock = sersock.accept();
```

Client connects to server and sends "hello" and closes connection.

```
1. Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 1101);
2. PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
3. write.println("Hello");
4. write.close();
```

Server reads and prints line from input stream after a connection has been made then closes the reader.

```
3. InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
4. BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(read);
5. System.out.println(buf.readLine());
6. buf.close();
```